# Logical equality with different negations

Tags: logic

I need to show that $(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)=(\lnot P \land Q) \lor (P \land \lnot Q)$

I can flip the logical operators using DeMorgan's law and distribute the negations, but I do not end up with with the "mixed" negations on the right-hand side. I also see that I have a $\lnot P$ and $\lnot Q$, but they are not grouped as they are on the right-hand side.

I do not yet know of a law that allows me to achieve something like that; I do not see how associative or distributive laws help me here. I also do not want to show it via a truth table because I am interested in learning the reason behind it.

Edit: Here what I can do:

$$(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)=\lnot(\lnot((P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)))$$
$$(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)=\lnot(\lnot(P \lor Q) \lor \lnot(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q))$$
$$...$$

And I end up back where I started.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? It would be easier to see what went wrong.

Comment: Use Distributivity.

Comment: @PJK yes, i just edited in an example of how i just end up back where i started and cant figure out how to "mix" the negations.

Comment: @tau As suggested by Mauro, you will have to use the distributive law: $A\wedge (B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C)$. Take $A$ as $P\vee Q$, $B$ as $\neg P$ and $C$ as $\neg Q$.

Comment: oh interesting, i didnt realize i could distribute like that, but it makes perfect sense. i will try it out! thanks.